# How to make an object morph into a cloud?

Tags: animation, objects, volumetrics

I want to make an animation where a ghost slowly morphs into a volumetric cloud. What's the best looking way to do that?

Comment: Shape keys definetely: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDu6y_2jFg0&ab_channel=SouthernShotty

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is not answerable at the moment for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you tell us only you know your exact setup. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some reference images of what effect you are trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button under the post. Editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.